# Android: Ringtone is being saved, but not set as the Active/Default ringtone

Tags: java, android, ringtone

I'm working on an Android application that allows users to long-click on a button to save a sound as a ringtone.  I am using the code below to do so.  The code currently works to save the file in the list of ringtones to be used, however it does not automatically set the sound as the default ringtone.  I have searched all around and not had much luck finding a clear guide on saving a sound as the default/active ringtone.

As of now, the user can long-click the button, then go into the Menu > Sounds > Phone Ringtone menu and select from the list, but that seems a bit inconvenient when I know that it is possible to have it simply set as the active ringtone straight away.

Any insight as to what I am missing?  Much appreciated!

```
public boolean saveas(int ressound){  
      byte[] buffer=null;  
      InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);  
      int size=0;  

      try {  
       size = fIn.available();  
       buffer = new byte[size];  
       fIn.read(buffer);
       fIn.close();  
      } catch (IOException e) {  
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
       return false;  
      }  

      String path="/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones/";  
      String filename="ADTone"+".ogg";  

      boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();  
      if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}  

      FileOutputStream save;  
      try {  
       save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);  
       save.write(buffer);  
       save.flush();  
       save.close();  
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
       return false;  
      } catch (IOException e) {  
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
       return false;  
      }      

      sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename)));  

      File k = new File(path, filename);  

      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
      values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());  
      values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "AD Ringtone");  
      values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");  
      values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "adtone ");  
      values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);  
      values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);  
      values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);  
      values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);  

      //Insert it into the database  
      this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath()), values);  


      return true;  
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you figured this one out, but I just did recently.  Replace your Insert Database line with this:

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());

            getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);

            Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                    YOURACTIVITYNAME.this,
              RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
              newUri
            );
```